# Ubuntu 12.04 error message E: dpkg was interrupted

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, package-management, dpkg

In Ubuntu 12.04 I got an error message saying:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

After I ran that command, nothing happened and the same error message appeared when I tried again.

Answer (score 1):

Probably some package's configure script had a problem. When you run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` you probably see a bunch of output on the screen; I highly doubt that it "just" fails. Without seeing the entire output of what the error message is, it's hard to know what the problem is. The reason for package manager failure could be almost anything, from bad disk blocks, to incomplete downloads of DEB files, to programming errors in the package upgrade/install scripts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

just see the issue fixed flow

**E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.**

> pd@admin:~$ **sudo dpkg --configure -a** 
>   dpkg: error: parsing file '*/var/lib/dpkg/updates/0024*' near line 0:  newline in field name `#padding'

pd@admin:~$ **sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/updates/0024**

pd@admin:~$ **sudo dpkg --configure -a**

pd@admin:~$ **sudo apt-get install appname_mention_here**

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done

**Now its working the installation....!**